# PL/SQL query with parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am familiar with `MSSQL` and using a parameter within the query, but I am not sure how I would do this within `PL/SQL`.

```
DECLARE 
LSITEID  NUMBER := 100001;

BEGIN

SELECT * from invoicehead ih
JOIN sitemaster sm on sm.SITEIID = ih.SITEIID
JOIN invoiceline il on il.invoiceIID = ih.invoiceIID
WHERE 
ih.StartDate BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-03-07'
AND SITEIID IN ( LSITEID)


END;
```

Right now I am testing this within Pl/SQL. But essentially I would be passing in the query with the parameter from `MSSQL Linked Server` `OPENQuery`.

How I can run the above query in PL/SQL with the parameter?

Comment: [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) doesn't seem to allow parameters, so presumably you'd have to construct the statement with the variable embedded in it? Your PL/SQL block isn't selecting into anything so isn't valid, but I'm not sure you want PL/SQL at all really. You should also not be replying on implicit date conversion or NLS settings; looks like you can use date literals though, since you'll also have to embed those.

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of other resource for finding an answer, e.g. [here (Tutorialspoint)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_functions.htm) or specifically [here (plsql-tutorial)](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-passing-parameters-procedure-function.htm).  But perhaps I have missed your point.

To not remain on merely citing links, your query could look like this:

```
DECLARE
  LSITEID integer;

BEGIN
  LSITEID := 100001;
  -- dostuff
END;
```

Two things to note:  First, in a declare part (as I have learnt it) you should avoid assigning values.  Second, if you intend to pass in different parameters you could/should use a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL you just use the name of the argument. In the following example, the argument is `P_VALUE`, note select statement says `where dummy = p_value`.

```
DECLARE
   FUNCTION dummycount (p_value IN DUAL.dummy%TYPE)
      RETURN INTEGER
   AS
      l_ret   INTEGER;
   BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT (*) c
        INTO l_ret
         FROM DUAL
       WHERE dummy = p_value;

       RETURN l_ret;
    END dummycount;
 BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('A: ' || dummycount (p_value => 'A'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('X: ' || dummycount (p_value => 'X'));
END;
```

This results in the following output:

```
A: 0
X: 1
```